# Plan Hash value for the SQL statement is "0" in V$SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, database-administration

There are lot of SQLs in V$SQL having 0 as Plan Hash Value(PHV). When I generate plan for that SQL it's showing some PHV by using below command,

```
explain plan for sql_query;
SELECT PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY());
```

But while executing it's showing 0 as PHV. Why some SQLs have a PHV of 0 in V$SQL view? Does this mean that it is executing with default plan?

Answer (score 3):

Is your SQL using a DB link? If yes then you will see the Hash value in the remote server. Also, if the SQL query is a PL/SQL block then you might get a plan hash value of 0